How to solve many-to-many relationship for inserting an element in Sequelize?
I have the following tables in my MySQL database:
CREATE TABLE idi_ma_products (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    image VARCHAR(255),
    created_date DATE,
    qualification ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),
    gender_id INT,
    kind_id INT,
    deletedAt DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    createdAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updatedAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (gender_id) REFERENCES idi_ma_genders(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (kind_id) REFERENCES idi_ma_kind(id)
);

CREATE TABLE idi_ma_characters (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    image VARCHAR(255),
    name VARCHAR(255),
    age INT,
    weight DECIMAL(5, 2),
    history TEXT,
    deletedAt DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    createdAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updatedAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE idi_re_characters_products (
    character_id INT,
    product_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (character_id, product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (character_id) REFERENCES idi_ma_characters(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES idi_ma_products(id)
);

I am working on a backend built with Express and currently using Sequelize ORM to handle the database models. These are the models that represent the tables I showed you earlier:
File model/character.ts
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import db from '../db/conn';
import Product from './product'; // Import Product at the beginning
import CharacterProduct from './characterproduct';

const Character = db.define('idi_ma_character', {
    image: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    age: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    weight: {
        type: DataTypes.DECIMAL
    },
    history: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
}, {
    paranoid: true
});

export default Character;

File model/product.ts
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import db from '../db/conn';
import Gender from './gender';
import Kind from './kind';

const Product = db.define('idi_ma_products', {
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    image: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    created_date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    qualification: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
    },
    gender_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    kind_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
}, {
    paranoid: true
});

Product.belongsTo(Gender, { foreignKey: 'gender_id', as: 'gender' });
Product.belongsTo(Kind, { foreignKey: 'kind_id', as: 'kind' });

export default Product;

Fiel model/characterproduct.ts
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import db from '../db/conn';
import Character from './character';
import Product from './product';

const CharacterProduct = db.define('idi_re_characters_products', {
    character_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    product_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
});

Character.belongsToMany(Product, { foreignKey: 'character_id', through: CharacterProduct });
Product.belongsToMany(Character, { foreignKey: 'product_id', through: CharacterProduct });

export default CharacterProduct;

Currently, I have an issue with creating the controller that allows me to add a character with its related movies.
This is my current controller:
export const createCharacter = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    const { body, file } = req;

    try {
        const { products, ...data } = body;

        const character = await Character.create({
            ...data,
            image: file?.filename
        });

        const productsArray: number[] = JSON.parse(products);

        if (productsArray && productsArray.length > 0) {
            const productsDB = await Product.findAll({
                where: {
                    id: productsArray
                }
            });
            await character.addProduct(productsDB);
        }

        await character.save();
        res.json(body);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({
            msg: 'Ha ocurrido un error creando el Personaje, contacte el administrador.'
        })
    }
}

This is the payload that I send by postman:

sequelize is supposed to internally generate a method for adding relationships (addProduct), but in my case it is not recognizing it.
ERROR: Property 'products' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any>'.ts(2339)
Additionally, I attach the resource that I relied on to solve my problem: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/.
My dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.7",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/swagger-jsdoc": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6"
  }


It seems like you need to define models using init and to extend model classes with explicitly declared methods using utility mixin types from Sequelize like 'HasManyGetAssociationsMixin' (see examples here: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript )
